# How to Convert the SQL Server Query to Equivelent SQLite Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have this query which works in SQL server:

```
SELECT 
  T_Cbt.cbtName,
  T_HDD.hddName,
  T_HDD.ip,
  T_HDD.compName,
  T_Cbt.mobRack,
  T_HDD.size, 
  T_OS.osName + ' ' + T_OS.osVersion + ' - ' + T_OS.osLanguage AS Expr1,
  T_OS.osBit, 
  T_SWList.swName + ' ' + T_SWDetails.swVersion + ' - ' + T_SWDetails.swLang + ' ' + T_SWDetails.swArch AS Expr2
FROM T_OS INNER JOIN
  T_Cbt INNER JOIN
  T_HDD ON T_Cbt.cbtId = T_HDD.cbtId ON T_OS.id = T_HDD.osId INNER JOIN
  T_Division ON T_HDD.division = T_Division.divId LEFT OUTER JOIN
  T_SWDetails INNER JOIN
  T_SW ON T_SWDetails.sdPk = T_SW.swdid INNER JOIN
  T_SWList ON T_SWDetails.swdId = T_SWList.swId ON T_HDD.hddid = T_SW.hddid
WHERE T_Cbt.cbtName <> 'FREE'
ORDER BY T_Cbt.purpose
```

While i am executing this query in Sqlite i get error like `Error while executing query: near "ON": syntax error` How to fix it?

Comment: Issue in your joins. You have to take On after inner join tablename.

Comment: @DH__  But it works in SQL Server. How to convert it to sqlite. I have no idea. Bcoz i'm new for sqlite

Comment: I don't know how it runs on sql server. It is totally wrong in both programming lng.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does not allow nesting `JOIN` and `ON` arbitrarily. Reordering your `JOIN`s to not use nesting should allow the query to execute without a problem;

```
SELECT 
  T_Cbt.cbtName, T_HDD.hddName, T_HDD.ip, T_HDD.compName, 
  T_Cbt.mobRack, T_HDD.size, 
  T_OS.osName || ' ' || T_OS.osVersion || ' - ' || T_OS.osLanguage AS Expr1,
  T_OS.osBit, T_SWList.swName || ' ' || T_SWDetails.swVersion || ' - ' ||
  T_SWDetails.swLang || ' ' || T_SWDetails.swArch AS Expr2
FROM T_OS 
INNER JOIN T_HDD ON T_OS.id = T_HDD.osId 
INNER JOIN T_Cbt ON T_Cbt.cbtId = T_HDD.cbtId   
INNER JOIN T_Division ON T_HDD.division = T_Division.divId 
INNER JOIN T_SW ON T_HDD.hddid = T_SW.hddid
LEFT OUTER JOIN T_SWDetails ON T_SWDetails.sdPk = T_SW.swdid 
INNER JOIN T_SWList ON T_SWDetails.swdId = T_SWList.swId 
WHERE (T_Cbt.cbtName <> 'FREE')
ORDER BY T_Cbt.purpose
```

Comment: Sorry, I got the answer || is for appending string in SQLITE not +

Comment: @Sam1604 Ah yes, sorry, didn't have any data to test on, so missed that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757945/how-to-select-row-number-in-sqlite Can you please help me to fix the problem.